# Typescript - how can i add a custom property to express. Request with two or more types?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have a problem. I know how to add a custom property to `Express.Request`, but i dont know how to give that custom property two or more types. For example i have `a.ts` and `b.ts`. These file export a function as default. And i import them in `c.ts`. All those functions add the same property to `Express.Request`. But those functions, add different types of functions as value! Look at this example:
a.ts:

```
    declare module "express-serve-static-core" {
      interface Request {
        store: (name: string) => number
      }
    }
    
    const func1 = (req:Request, res:Response) => {
       req.store = (name) => {
       return setInStore(name)
       }
    }
export default func1;
```

b.ts:

```
    declare module "express-serve-static-core" {
      interface Request {
        store: (key: number) => string
      }
    }
    
    const func2 = (req:Request, res:Response) => {
       req.store = (key) => {
          return getFromStore(key);
       }
    }
export default func2;
```

but when i set the type in `b.ts`, i will get error from `a.ts`. it says that type `(name: string) => number` is not assignable to type `(key: number) => string`.

and i think that there is an other way instead of using conditional types.
so how can i change the type of `store` property to `(name: string) => number` if user used the func1 middleware and change the type of `store` to `(key: number) => string` if user used func2 thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not express user. maybe you can config the type through generics too which is easier

anyway, what you want to do is not possible. however, you can go with one of these solutions:

#### 1. unions

if the `store` functions supports both value, then it is not important which type in which function you are using... so you can use union

```
(key: string | number) => void
```

#### 2. more specific function name

split the `store` function into 2 seperate functions like this

```
storeByName: (name: string) => void
storeById: (id: number) => void
```

Comment: Thank you arash. You made me sure that there is no way to do that. I used function overloading and i got other strange errors from ts. thank you :)